# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha de modificación de un archivo zip en PHP?

Tags: php7

Quiero obtener la fecha de modificación de un archivo zip, estuve intentando con esta línea de código pero no me devuelve la fecha correcta:

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) {
  echo $file.' - '.date("F d Y H:i:s.",fileatime($file));
}
```

Comment: ¿No será [**`filemtime`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filemtime.php)?...

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo probé así y me funciona correctamente

```
<?php
    $dir="ruta";;
    $dh = opendir($dir);
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        echo $file.' - '.date("F d Y H:i:s.",fileatime($file));
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Otra forma, filtrando solo los archivo `zip`

```
<?php
    $dir = "C:/Users/undirectorio/";

    $files= glob($directory . "*.zip");
    foreach ($files as $filename) {
        echo $filename.' - '.date("F d Y H:i:s.",fileatime($filename));
    }
?>
```